# How to create am image of existing EC2(AWS) and containerase it in my local machine's Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, containers, migrate

I am learning Docker as I implement a new project and i have a question which I am sure one of you out there will have the answer:

How to create am image from an existing EC2(AWS) Instance(with my own personalised configurations) and then "containerise" it with Docker in my local machine. Just so i use all the preexisting configurations from that remote linux based EC2(AWS) without the need to re-do all the package installations from scratch in my local machine's docker container.

Is there someone out there that can layout the steps I need take to do that?

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process; an EC2 instance is a complete running multi-process system.  They're very different things and you can't directly import an instance (or another VM image) into a Docker image.

Comment: thanks for elucidating the difference of those two concepts. When you a beginner there will always be gap holes that only time or personalized(one2one) explanation can fill.